# Multiple <buttons> in single form - Values not getting passed to POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

It's been an hour of straight out binging on SO and can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I have a single form that has multiple buttons.

**Buttons:**

1. Fetch Email
2. Save
3. Skip
4. Ban

The first one fetches an email address from MySQL using Ajax. This one works fine.

The last 3 should refresh the page and perform an action based on the value.

The problem is that the button tags are not getting passed through to POST. All other form fields get passed without a problem.

I've built it using Chrome, tested on Firefox and IE and the same issue occurs. No  submit values.

Here's some of the JS that's involved

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //saves and goes to next page
        function submitForm(action)
        {
            document.getElementById('ajaxform').action = action;
            document.getElementById('ajaxform').submit();
        }
```

**Form **

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="inc/scripts/email_api.php" method="POST"  >
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required />
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $domain;?>" name="domainName" id="domainName">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $article_id;?>" name="articleId" id="articleId">
<button id="run-code" name="getEmail" onclick="return validateForm()" >Run Code</button>
<input type="radio" value="blog" name="websiteType" id="blog">
<input type="radio" value="junk" name="websiteType" id="junk">
<input type="radio" value="guest" name="websiteType" id="guest">
<input type="button" name="save" value="save" onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>')" id="saveContinue" disabled />
<input type="button" name="skip" value="skip" onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>')" id="skip" />
<input type="button" name="ban" value="ban" onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>')" id="ban" />
</form>
```

I should also mention that I have tried having it as type="submit" and the values still do not get passed. I have also tried with having all of the buttons have the same name, but that did not work either.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you submit the form via JS then button values don't get submitted, but you can pass the value of the clicked button through to `submitForm()` and have it set that value into a `type="hidden"` input. . If you need to submit to URL 1 and then redirect to URL 2, why aren't you using Ajax for the submission?

Comment: @nnnnnn I can see this working too. I found a simpler workaround that I just posted below. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

`type="button"` elements do not get submitted in a form

Try changing to `type="submit"` which by default will submit the form without needing any javascript

Comment: Tried this as well and it doesn't work. I've never run into this problem before and have had multiple buttons like this. 

The reason for the onclick to direct to a new page is because the form's action goes to the ajax file. I need that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem for anyone else struggling with this.

The issue was submitting the submit buttons using the line of Javascript which I found here on SO.

I'm no expert in JS, but for whatever reason, the function was preventing the post Vars from being sent. So I found a workaround to add an onclick outside of a function to the buttons.

```
                    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save" onclick='this.form.action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"' id="save" disabled />
                    <input type="submit" name="skip" value="skip" onclick='this.form.action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"' id="skip" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ban" value="ban" onclick='this.form.action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"' id="ban" />
```

After doing this, the buttons would no longer work. So the trick to fix this is to add `novalidate` to your `<form>` tag.